# Not able to run Java program through command line, but able to run using Eclipse

Tags: java

While I am Converting DICOM Image from dicom to jpg getting below error, when I run  This Java program  through CMD
,  but When I run same  program in eclipse it is working fine

Error :

```
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" org.dcm4che2.data.ConfigurationError: No Image Reader of class com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg.CLibJPEGImageReader available for format:jpeg
    at org.dcm4che2.imageio.ImageReaderFactory.getReaderForTransferSyntax(ImageReaderFactory.java:99)
    at org.dcm4che2.imageioimpl.plugins.dcm.DicomImageReader.initCompressedImageReader(DicomImageReader.java:410)
    at org.dcm4che2.imageioimpl.plugins.dcm.DicomImageReader.initImageReader(DicomImageReader.java:395)
    at org.dcm4che2.imageioimpl.plugins.dcm.DicomImageReader.read(DicomImageReader.java:636)
    at DICOMToJPEGConverter.main(DICOMToJPEGConverter.java:26)
```

Comment: Libraries you have in your build path/classpath in Eclipse are not in your classpath when you run it in command line.

Comment: How can I find the libraries that are using on command line

Answer (score 0):

When you are running from your eclipse project, please check all the libraries are there in build path.

you can give all the libraries along with **java** command while trying to run the program.

When you execute java, it looks for availability of libraries in classpath. So if you will add these libraries to classpath that will work

To add these libraries from command line:

```
java -cp <all_the_libraries> <programe_to_execute>
```